# Teams Graph API, Retrieving files from each Teams channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to retrieve all of the files associated with each channel within each Team. Per the Microsoft Graph REST API V1.0 documentation, it is GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/filesFolder.\

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-filesfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

However, filesFolder no longer appears as an available query. Is there still a way to achieve this?

Edit: Appears to be the same for Messages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0

Why are these queries no longer available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query Groups with team-id to get the items from the group's drive directly.

You can use [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{team-id}/drive/root/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bteam-id%7D/drive/root/children) where /drive/root can get the Document library that the channel folders are part of and /children can display all items from the folder. Referto this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more details on how to get a DriveItem.

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me. This is the snippet of my code:

var sites = await _graphClient.Groups[team.Id].Drive.Root.Children
                           .Request()
                           .GetAsync();

For some strange reason, all of my counts were 0 even though some of those channels clearly had some files in them. Is there a way to retrieve the sharepoint URL for each channel's file storage instead??

Comment: I got the URL. Thank you! Do you happen to know about the messages in my edited opening?

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/[team-id]/channels/[channel-id]/messages works for me on graph explorer but it is beta and not in v1.0.

Comment: Thank you. After updating Microsoft.Graph to 3.16 from 1.15, I now see this option. 

The problem now is that I'm getting this error:

Message = "Code: UnknownError\r\nInner error:\r\n\tAdditionalData:\r\n\tdate: 2020-10-08T23:00:24\r\n\trequest-id: \r\n\tclient-request-id: \r\nClientRequestId: ...